# Intuition behind this equivalence.

Tags: number-theory

So here's a simple question that I encountered and I am failing to grasp why this way to solve the question works.
The question is as follows:
Set A contains numbers $\{1+3d,d\geq0
\}$ and set B contains numbers $\{9+7m,m\geq 0\}$. How many elements are in the union of the first $2004$ terms in each set? I solved this question using linear congruences, but to my surprise there exists a simple solution, here is how it begins:

Shift down the first sequence by $1$ and the second by $9$ so that the two sequences become $0,3,6,\cdots,6009$ and $0,7,14,\cdots,14028$. The first becomes multiples of $3$ and the second becomes multiples of $7$. Their intersection is the multiples of $21$ up to $6009$..........

How does this work? It doesn't make sense to me intuitively, since suppose I want the union of set $\{1\}$ and $\{9\}$, using the method above I would get $1$ term but the answer is actually $2$.

Comment: It is not perfectly clear to me what numbers are contained in set $A$.  Are these the numbers which are equivalent to $1\pmod{3}$?  And set $B$, are these the numbers which are $2\pmod{7}$?  Why don't you include $2$ in $B$?

Comment: If my assumption is correct, then this becomes an application of the [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) and inclusion-exclusion.  The intersection would be those numbers which are $16\pmod{21}$ in the range.

Comment: @JMoravitz I agree, edited.